adding watermark when processing several images in batch?
I'm adding several images to one pdf using imagemagick, and currently i'm duplicating all images in another directory just to add a watermark on them.
Is there a way to do this in one pass?
one example of my batch commands:
convert -adaptive-resize '150%' -page 2480x3508 -extent 2480x3508   -density 300 -quality 68  -gravity Center src/images*.jpg  out.pdf

Above example command will scale all images, center them in an A4 @300dpi and drop quality to 68%. Now I would also like to add watermark.png which is already transparent on top of each image (watermark image can be provided in the size of the original images or the full size of the a4 page)

Without having your images it is hard to know exactly what you want. But try this in Imagemagick.
convert src/images*.jpg -adaptive-resize '150%' -page 2480x3508 -extent 2480x3508 -density 300 -quality 68 NULL: watermark.png -gravity Center -compose over -layers composite out.pdf

